# Google Sheets - How to parse link with data from another cell?

Tags: google-sheets

Basically, cell A has an ID number in it. I want the adjacent cell B to contain a link to that ID page on my website. So for example, | 938294839 | website.com/938294839 | Is there anyway to automatically generate the link based off info in another cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just assemble the string:

```
A1   |  B1
----------
stem | =concat("https://website.com/", $A1)
```

Sheets will detect the resulting link for you.

Answer (score 0):

all you need is:

```
="https://website.com/"&A1
```

for array it would be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA("https://website.com/"&A1:A10)
```